# Get div class title content text using xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I have a requirement of getting the text below of "ELECTRONIC ARTS" (this can change according to data) using class title "Offered By" (this class will be same for all) using Xpath. I tried various xpath coding, but couldn't get the results I want. I'm really looking for someone's help on this.

```
<div class="meta-info"> 
<div class="title"> Offered By</div> 
<div class="content">ELECTRONIC ARTS</div> </div>
```

Comment: Hi , i don't have much knowledge on Xpath, i tried //div[@class='content'] , but it doesn't give my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible XPath expression to starts with, which then you can simplify or add more criteria as needed (XPath formatted to be more readable) :

```
//div[
    @class='meta-info' 
        and 
    div[@class='title' and normalize-space()='Offered By']
]/div[@class='content']
```

**explanation :**

- `//div[@class='meta-info' and ...` : find `div` element where `class` attribute value equals `"meta-info"` and ...
- `div[@class='title' and normalize-space()='Offered By']]` : ... has child element `div` where `class` attribute value equals `"title"` and content equals `"Offered By"`
- `/div[@class='content']` : from such `div` (the `<div class="meta-info">` to be clear), return child element `div` where `class` attribute value equals `"content"`

Answer (score 0):

Using the examples on [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript):

```js
var xpath = document.evaluate("//div[@class='content']", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);

document.write('The text found is: "' + xpath.stringValue + '".');
console.log(xpath);
```

```html
<div class="meta-info"> 
  <div class="title"> Offered By</div> 
  <div class="content">ELECTRONIC ARTS</div>
</div>
```

By the way, I think `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` are much more convenient in this situation:

```js
var content = document.querySelector('.meta-info .content').innerText;

document.write('The text found is: "' + content + '".');
console.log(content);
```

```html
<div class="meta-info"> 
  <div class="title"> Offered By</div> 
  <div class="content">ELECTRONIC ARTS</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want answer in this format     //div[@class='content']

Comment: Ok, so use that one then. You're free to use the one you like best.